# Are other layer 2 protocols than Ethernet possible over a TAP device?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tun

When using a TAP-device, does someone know, if it is possible to use other layer 2 protocols than Ethernet, e.g. PPP oder FDDI?

All examples, I could find only use Ethernet, but the kernel documentation 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt is not specific about this.

It is not required, that the host kernel can handle the custom layer 2 frames. If I can use tools like Wireshark and Scapy to handle the traffic, that is fine.

Before I try to built an interface to a TAP device, that will not work, I wanted to check, if someone has tried this before.